# "ImportError: No module named pkg_resources" for Ubuntu 16.04 when installing ethereumjs. How can I fix this?

Tags: 16.04, nodejs, npm, ethereum

I'm following [this](https://medium.com/@gus_tavo_guim/how-to-create-token-and-initial-coin-offering-contracts-using-truffle-openzeppelin-1b7a5dae99b6) tutorial to create Ethereum smart contracts for a crowdsale. I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 and I've been stuck on this problem for several hours and haven't had any luck solving it. I looked up failed to fetch errors and some were similar, but none of the proposed solutions worked.

When I type:

```
npm install -g ethereumjs-testrpc
```

into the terminal, I get these errors:

```
ImportError: No module named pkg_resources
gyp ERR! configure error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/usr/share/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:354:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 3.16.0-77-generic
gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/node-gyp" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ethereumjs-testrpc/node_modules/scrypt
gyp ERR! node -v v4.2.6
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.0.3
gyp ERR! not ok 
/usr/local/lib
└── (empty)

npm ERR! Linux 3.16.0-77-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/nodejs" "/usr/bin/npm" "install" "-g" "ethereumjs-testrpc"
npm ERR! node v4.2.6
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! scrypt@6.0.3 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the scrypt@6.0.3 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the scrypt package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs scrypt
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls scrypt
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/fappycow/npm-debug.log
npm ERR! code 1
```

Any idea how I might fix these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your version of Node.js is too old. As you can see from the error log, your version of Node.js is 4.2.6 but `ethereum-testrpc` "requires at least Node 6.9.1 to run" as stated in https://github.com/ethereumjs/testrpc. For installing Node.js >= 6.x, see the instructions for Ubuntu at https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/#debian-and-ubuntu-based-linux-distributions, which I reproduce verbatim below:

- Node.js 6.x

  ```
  curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo -E bash -
  sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
  ```
- Node.js 8.x

  ```
  curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo -E bash -
  sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
  ```

Comment: It appears to be working. And you, sir, are a godsend :)